# EATON/MGE 5E UPS - driver not working

Tags: ups, nut

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.2 on a Dell 7010 (i5-3570S) and own an EATON 5E 850i (former MGE). I've read and tried various guides, including all answers here: [How to configure UPC with USB connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563717/how-to-configure-upc-with-usb-connection)

When running `upsdrvctl start` and I'm still getting:

```
Network UPS Tools - UPS driver controller 2.7.2
Network UPS Tools - Generic HID driver 0.38 (2.7.2)
USB communication driver 0.32
No matching HID UPS found
Driver failed to start (exit status=1)
```

One snag is that after reboot the UPS is no longer seen by `lsusb`. I need to manually unplug and replug the USB cable, and then it shows up.

`lsusb` says:

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 152d:1561 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 042: ID 0463:ffff MGE UPS Systems UPS
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lsusb -v` says:

```
# lsusb -v -d 0463:ffff

Bus 003 Device 042: ID 0463:ffff MGE UPS Systems UPS
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x0463 MGE UPS Systems
  idProduct          0xffff UPS
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           1 (error)
  iProduct                2 (error)
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               20mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode           33 US
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     549
          Warning: incomplete report descriptor
          Report Descriptor: (length is 9)
            Item(Main  ): (null), data=none
            Item(Main  ): (null), data=none
            Item(Main  ): (null), data=none
            Item(Main  ): (null), data=none
            Item(Main  ): (null), data=none
            Item(Main  ): (null), data=none
            Item(Main  ): (null), data=none
            Item(Main  ): (null), data=none
            Item(Main  ): (null), data=none
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              20
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of scratching, it turned out that the USB cable was too long: I used a 5m USB cable which works fine with a printer, but in this UPS' case fails when there is more communication on it. Using a 1m cable (*) worked fine and I could talk to the UPS successfully.

(*) I went full paranoid and also added a ferrite core on the cable ...

Comment: I found that even using a higher quality cable with a moulded-on choke core, the USB connection is flaky at best, presumably due to interference produced by the UPS itself. At this point I've incurred more server downtime in trying to configure this device than it is ever likely to save. Eaton's own marketing (including the instruction manual) seems suspiciously low-key on the USB connector, suggesting Eaton is well aware that their product isn't fit for purpose, but are happy to sell it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems; the USB connection is not stable. For me, lsusb did not even show the device with the original cable on reboot. Unplugging and plugging the Device did make the device show up then in lsusb and also let me load the driver.

Changing the cable did not help either (two other cables (even shorter than one meter) tried). What helped in the end was putting an USB-Hub in between.

See also https://github.com/networkupstools/nut/issues/515.